# Where to find sqlite database using Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

In Eclipse we can use the DDMS to find where the sqlite database is stored in an Android project. Where or what do we use to find it in Android Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `android studio` you have to follow the same steps. By clicking on `Android Device Monitor`[*android robot icon , left to help icon* ] you can see `DDMS` and `File Explorer` and next you can find your `sqlite data` .